# Simplifying an Euler-Cauchy differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi i've been struggling with this one:

A solution of the following Euler-Cauchy equation can be obtained in the form $y_1(x)= x^n$ or $e^{ax}$

$x^2(x^2+1)y''-2x^3y'+2(x^2-1)y=0$

I have tried substituting for $y$ using the Ansatz $y=x^n$ as suggested
and get :

$x^n[n(n-1)(x^2+1) -2nx^{-2}+2(x^2+1)]=0$

which is of course not quite of the form $x^n(n(n-1)-2n+2)=0$

which would then be easy to factorise in order to get the two roots $n=1$ and $n=2$

I also know the change of variable method,

e.g: $(x+1)^2y''+3(x+1)y'+0.75y=0$

, where  we seek solutions of the
form $y=(x+1)^n$ for $x+1>0$.

Everything is quite straight-forward for the latter example however i am confused as to what to do with my former equation. May someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is here :

[image]

$$(n(n-1)-2n+2)x^2+(n(n-1)-2)=0$$
implies $n^2-3n+2=0$ and $n^2-n-2=0$

The only value of $n$ is $n=2$.